Behavior of a Wishart quadratic form
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ be a random matrix with iid standard Gaussian entries. Let $e_1$ denote the first canonical basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Define
$$
P_d(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) e_1 e_1^T + \lambda \tfrac{1}{d} I_d, \quad \lambda \in (0, 1].
$$
I am trying to understand the behavior of the random variable
$$
V_{n, d}(\lambda) = n \,  e_1^T\Big(X^T X + P_d(\lambda)^{-1}\Big)^{-1} e_1, \quad \lambda \in (0, 1].
$$
Question: What is the behavior of $F(n, d, \lambda) = \mathbb{E}[V_{n, d}(\lambda)]$? Specifically, fix any $\lambda \in (0, 1]$. Is there a choice of $d = d(n, \lambda)$ such that the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} F\Big(n, d(n,\lambda), \lambda\Big)
$$
exists, and is finite and nonzero?
Below I compute a few examples---these are the easy cases---I do not know how to deal with $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ general.
Example 1 ($\lambda = 1$): A classical example is when $\lambda = 1$. In this case, we have
$$
F(n, d, 1) = \mathbb{E} ~ \tfrac{1}{d} \mathrm{tr}\Big(\big(\tfrac{1}{n} X^T X + \tfrac{d}{n} I_d\big)^{-1}\Big)
$$
Hence if for $\gamma \in (0, \infty)$, we set $d(n, 1) = \gamma n + o(n)$ (for instance, the floor of $\gamma n$), we have
$$
F(n, d(n, 1), 1) \to \int \frac{1}{\lambda + \gamma} \, \mathrm{d}\mu^{\sf MP}_\gamma(\lambda), 
$$
where $\mu^{\sf MP}_\gamma$ denotes the Marchenko-Pastur law, with parameter $\gamma$.
It does not appear that this method works well when $\lambda \neq 1$, since then we have some contribution, in $P_d(\lambda)$, from the matrix $e_1 e_1^T$.
Example 2 ($\lambda = 0$): Note that we have for all $\lambda \in (0, 1]$,
$$
V_{n, d}(\lambda) = n e_1^T Q(\lambda)(Q(\lambda) X^T X Q(\lambda) + I)^{-1} Q(\lambda) e_1, 
$$
where $Q(\lambda) = P(\lambda)^{1/2}$. The advantage of the above representation is that it extends to $\lambda = 0$ naturally, yielding, in distribution
$$
V_{n, d}(0) = \Big(\tfrac{1}{n}\chi^2_n + \tfrac{1}{n}\Big)^{-1}.
$$
It is easy to see from this that $F(n, d(n, 0), 0) \to 1$,
for any choice of $d(n, 0)$.

We can invert $P=P_d(\lambda)$ easily because it is diagonal:
$$
P^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda + \lambda/d} e_1e_1^T + \frac{d}{\lambda} \sum_{j\ge 2} e_j e_j^T.
$$
Write $P^{-1}$ as $\frac{d}{\lambda} I_d  - y e_1 e_1^T$ and apply the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula with $A=X^TX + (d/\lambda) I_d$:
$$
(A - ye_1e_1^T)^{-1}
=
A^{-1}
+
\frac{y}{1-y e_1^T A^{-1} e_1} A^{-1}e_1e_1^TA^{-1}.
$$
Multiplying by $y e_1^T$ on the left and $e_1$ on the right, the right-hand side depends only on $y e_1^T A^{-1} e_1$ which has a finite limit, say $L(\lambda,\gamma)$, under the proportional scaling $d/n \to \gamma$ and the Marchenko-Pastur law.
To see that $y e_1^T A^{-1} e_1$ has a finite limit, observe
$$
\text{trace}(A^{-1})
$$
has a limit in probability depending only on $(\lambda,\gamma)$ thanks to the Marcenko-Pastur result. Furthermore, $y/d =\lambda + o(1)$ so that
$$
\frac{y}{d}\text{trace}(A^{-1})
$$
also has a finite limit in probability depending only on $(\gamma,\lambda)$.
It remains to link $\text{trace}(A^{-1})$ to $d e_1^T A^{-1} e_1$; we claim that the ratio converges to 1 in probability. To see this, $X=^d XP$ (equality in distribution) for any random rotation $P\in O(d)$ independent of $X$, so that $d e_1^T A^{-1} e_1$ is equal in distribution to
$$
d e_1^T (P^T X^T X + P^T (d/\lambda) P)^{-1} e_1
= 
d v^T (X^TX + (d/\lambda) )^{-1} v
= d v^T A^{-1} v
$$
where $v = P e_1$. By choosing $P$ distributed according to the Haar measure, $v$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. By concentration of quadratic forms of random vectors uniformly distributed on the sphere (or just Chebyshev's inequality),
$$
d v^T A^{-1} v
= \text{trace}(A^{-1}) + O_P(1) \|A^{-1}\|_F
$$
and the Frobenius norm $\|A^{-1}\|_F$ is of order $1/\sqrt d$.
In summary $d e_1^T A^{-1} e_1$ has the same limite as the limit of trace$[A^{-1}]$ given by the Marcenko-Pastur result.

I really would like to understand your argument, however I am a bit lost after “which has a finite limite…”

I expanded the answer. Let me know if this clears your doubts.

Can you read through my "rewritten" version of your solution? If it looks correct to you, I can accept your response.

It looks fine to me. One remark is that the constant $1-\lambda$ could be replaced by any other constant without changing the result. Also, these convergences related to the MP law should be quite fast ($n,d$ equal to a few hundred) and it is always a good idea to perform sanity checks via Monte Carlo simulations.

This is a slightly re-written version of jlewk's response (credit to them).
Set
$$
y = \frac{d}{\lambda} \frac{d(1-\lambda)}{d(1-\lambda) + \lambda}, \quad \lambda \in (0, 1).
$$
Evidently $y/n \to \gamma/\lambda$ if $d/n \to \gamma \in (0, \infty), n \to \infty$.
Using the Sherman-Morrison formula, it can be verified that
$$
n V_{n,d}(\lambda) = \frac{W_n(\lambda)}{1 - (y/n) W_n(\lambda)}, \quad W_n(\lambda) := e_1^TQ_n(\lambda)^{-1} e_1, \quad Q_n(\lambda) = \tfrac{1}{n} X^T X + \tfrac{d}{\lambda n} I_d 
$$
Let $g \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a standard Gaussian vector. Then in distribution
$$
W_n(\lambda) = \frac{A_n(\lambda)}{B_n} \quad A_n(\lambda) = (1/d) g^T Q_n(\lambda)^{-1} g, \quad B_n = \|g\|_2^2/d.
$$
By the Hanson-Wright inequality and strong law of large numbers, respectively, it can be shown that
$$
A_n(\lambda) - (1/d)\, \mathrm{trace}(Q_n(\lambda)^{-1}) \to 0, \quad \mbox{and} \quad B_n\to 1,
$$
in probability and almost surely, respectively, as $d/n \to \gamma \in (0, \infty), n \to \infty$.
Therefore,
$$
W_n(\lambda) = (1/d) \, \mathrm{trace}(Q_n(\lambda)^{-1}) + o_p(1), \quad n\to\infty
$$
and $d/n \to \gamma \in (0, \infty)$. To conclude, we apply the limit relation for $y/n$ and set for $\alpha > 0$,
$$
S_\gamma(\alpha) = \int \frac{1}{\lambda + \alpha} \, d\mu^{\sf MP}_\gamma(\lambda), 
$$
where $\mu^{\sf MP}_\gamma$ denotes the MP law with parameter $\gamma$.
Then we clearly have by continuous mapping and the MP theorem that
$$
n V_{n, d}(\lambda) \to \frac{S_\gamma(\gamma/\lambda)}{1 - (\gamma/\lambda) S_\gamma(\gamma/\lambda)}
$$
in probability as $n \to \infty, d/n \to \gamma \in (0, \infty)$.
